# Rename the filename using python

Tags: python, file-rename

I have folder where I have multiple files. Out of this files I want to rename some of them. For example: **PB report December21 North.xlsb**, **PB report November21 North.xslb** and so on. They all have a same start - **PB report**. I would like to change their name and leave only PB report and Month. For example **PB report December**.

I have tried this code:

```
import os

path = r'C://Users//greencolor//Desktop//Autoreport//Load_attachments//'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.startswith("PB report"):
     os.rename(filename, filename[:-8])
```

-8 indicates that I want to split the name from the end on the 8th character

I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's the purpose of this `[:-8]`? Gives me `PB report December21 No`

Comment: `filename[:-8]` This means everything from the beginning to the 8th last character.
"Hello Goodbye" would become "Hello"

Comment: @AchilleG I'm perfectly aware of ***what*** it does. I'm not sure ***why*** it is being used...

Comment: well because it erased XLSB too. I did not think that it would start erasing from the excel format. @Lewis already found a solution.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I know you're aware of what slicing is, I was answering Greencolor because I'm not sure this is what he wanted to achieve with this slicing

Comment: @AchilleG Oh. Well, it says in the question: *"-8 indicates that I want to split the name from the end on the 8th character"*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the path when renaming file with `os.rename`:

Replace:

```
os.rename(filename, filename[:-8])
```

With:

```
filename_part, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
os.rename(path+filename, path+filename_part[:-8]+extension)
```

Comment: It erased the file format (xlsb) too and of course its not an excel file anymore. But it did change the name as I wanted. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can do like this:
os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename[:-8], '.xlsb'))

Comment: @Greencolor Please see edit

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic example of how working with `os`/`os.path` to manipulate paths is just not convenient. This is why [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) exists. By treating paths as ***objects***, rather than *strings* everything becomes more sensible. By using a combination of [`path.iterdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) and [`path.rename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) you can achieve what you want like:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'your path')
for file in path.iterdir():
    if file.name.startswith("PB report"):
        file.rename(file.with_stem(file.stem[:-8]))
```

Note that [`stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) means the filename without the extension and that [`with_stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_stem) was added in Python 3.9. So for older versions you can still use [`with_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_name):

```py
        file.rename(file.with_name(file.stem[:-8] + file.suffix))
```

Where [`suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix) is the extension of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that it cannot find the file because the directory is not specified. You need to add the path to the file name:

```
import os

path = r'C://Users//greencolor//Desktop//Autoreport//Load_attachments//'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.startswith("PB report"):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename[:-8]))
```

Comment: now the problem is that it erased the xlsb too. Therefore they are no longer excel files

Comment: You can do like this: os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename[:-8], '.xlsb'))